# In EF.Core Map Single Entity to two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two table that have exactly the same schema. How can I create 1 entity in my code and map that single entity to the two different tables?

One option I tried was to create a second entity that inherits from the first, but have no additional properties defined:

```
public class EntityA {
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public string PropertyD { get; set; }
    public string PropertyE { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : EntityA {
}
```

In the database, I would have tables `EntityA` and `EntityB` with both having the exact same schema.

Using EF 6 or earlier, it seems that I had to do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .Map(map => { map.ToTable("EntityA") })
            .Map(map => { map.ToTable("EntityB") });
```

It however seems that the Map method cannot be found when I try to do this in EF Core.

What is the best solution for this, or would I just have two entities in C# where they look exactly the same?

Comment: Are they named the same?

Why do you want them mapped together?

Code First?

Comment: At the moment, I have one Entity and would want to use that single entity to be mapped to the two different tables. This is primarily to reduce duplication and make it easier if something would change (although the wins are small :) ). Code First yes. I tried the option explained above by creating a second entity and inheriting from the first, but then I get an error `no such column: a.Discriminator`

Answer (score 2):

Have both entities derive from a common base class which has all the common properties. That way, they share the *same class* to be shared amongst your code **after a cast**, but still keep the originality of being different as needed in the future.

⚠️ The downside is that you will, by hand, update these classes during any future changes.